# MissingMethodException while building .NET Core Project in a linux image in Azure Devops

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, mono, docker-image

We have a pipeline for our .net core project, using a linux image. The pipeline was working fine until we got this error while building with a cake task the application:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.0.0 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/bll/TestProject/TestProject.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageDependency> NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFileTargetLibrary.get_Dependencies() [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/bll/TestProject/TestProject.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.DependencyContextBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<GetLibraries>b__0 (NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFileTargetLibrary export) [0x00000] in <aafa1364e74c4a5ea60cdcaa95f71707>:0  [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/bll/TestProject/TestProject.csproj]
```

What can the reason be?
Do we need to update the .NET SDK in the image?

Comment: What did you use in your pipeline definition? There is nothing you should call from Mono, so when you showed MSBuild "for Mono" above, I can only say you are using the wrong tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MissingMethodException while building .NET Core Project in a linux image in Azure Devops

According to the error message, it seems the version mismatch in nuget between msbuild and dotnet core.

This issue already reported on Github:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/3155#issuecomment-497908500

To resolve this issue, you can try to update your dotnet core install to the latest stable version, like `2.2.300`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/net-core-support?view=vsmac-2019

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: you were right! So we fixed it by adding a job before the build script to use sdk 2.2.x.